# Sorting files in a List<string> by the elements filename number

Tags: c#, string, list, sorting

I have the following files in a `List<string>`

```
backup-codes (7).txt
backup-codes.txt
backup-codes (1).txt
backup-codes (2).txt
backup-codes (3).txt
backup-codes (8).txt
backup-codes (6).txt
```

How can I sort them by the number `(eg. (#) )` so that files with the highest value always appear first in the list?

Comment: @TinyGiant: bad duplicate suggestion. Here OP is asking for sorting the string based on the numeric value inside the string

Comment: @un-lucky wouldn't that just be a combination of _How to sort a List<string>_ and _How to extract a number from a string_?  Do we need to have a _How do I sort my list by W character of type X at position Y in input of type Z?_ for every W, X, Y, and Z?

Comment: @un-lucky that is because most questions asked today _are_ duplicates, at least for the most mature technologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
lstFiles = lstFiles.OrderByDescending(x=> int.Parse(Regex.Replace(x,"[^0-9]+","0"))).ToList<string>();
```

This assumes that there are no other digits in filename except for sequencing.

Here is fiddler : https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nb38fJ

Comment: Cheers! Worked perfectly :)